# inserting %d in pyplot legend does not work

Tags: python, matplotlib

Please look at the code below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

title = 25
plt.title('title is %d' % (title))

L = 15
plt.legend('L = %d' % L)
```

The title reproduces the number as intended. However the legend just leaves a blank space for where the number should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling [`plt.legend`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.legend) you have to pass in a sequence of strings, such as a list of strings.

The problem with just passing a single string in is that it will treat the string as a sequence (which it is) and only take the first element from it, which in this case happens to be the letter `L`.

Note that rather than passing your strings into `plt.legend()` it's more typical to use the keyword-argument `label = my_string` when calling `plt.plot` such that it looks something like `plt.plot(x, y, label='L = %d' % L)`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

title = 25
plt.title('title is %d' % (title))

plt.plot([1,2,3])

L = 15
plt.legend(['L = %d' % L])

plt.show()
```

[image: Example]